# Cordova - updating exportOptions plist with multiple target provisioning profiles to create ipa

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, target

We have build.json to provide the code signing keys to build the both iOS & Android like follows

```
{
  "ios": {
      "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Development",
            "provisioningProfile": "926c2bd6-8de9-4c2f-8407-1016d2d12954",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
            "provisioningProfile": "70f699ad-faf1-4adE-8fea-9d84738fb306",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

But in my case, I have multiple targets in `cordova` application. I want to build those by using the `build.json`. How can I add the multiple targets in `build.json`

I want to create `IPA` using cordova build command with multiple targets.
right now when i add multiple targets this build.json is not updating the provisioning profiles for my watch extension target so i need to open xcode and apply correct provisioning profile for those targets to build IPA so i want to automate this by applying some cordova build.json

Please help 
Thanks.